# Adding body to mailto:XXXX@email.com?Subject=Test in SharePoint list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, list-view, sharepoint-email

I am trying to add body to an email that i sending through JavaScript. I have a SharePoint list view when clicked on sends an email to EmailID.

This works fine,

```
var mail=&quot;mailto:&quot;+emailID+&quot;?Subject=Test:&quot;+ctx.CurrentItem.ID
```

I am trying to add body of the email. I have tried

`var mail=&quot;mailto:&quot;+emailID+&quot;?Subject=Test:&quot;+ctx.CurrentItem.ID&body=Test`

and

```
var mail=&quot;mailto:&quot;+emailID+&quot;?Subject=Test:&quot;+ctx.CurrentItem.ID;body=Test.
```

Nothing worked.

Can anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with double quotes.

Try it as below:

```
var mail= "mailto:" + emailID + "?Subject=Test: " + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "&body=Some body text";
```

If you want a dynamic body text, try it as below:

```
var bodyText= "some body text";
var mail= "mailto:" + emailID + "?Subject=Test: " + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "&body=" + bodyText;
```